# RuntimeSchema in Protostuff 1.3.8

Tags: java, protostuff

I am trying to learn how to use Protostuff. I have an example that uses protostuff 1.0.7. In this example the class RuntimeSchema is used.

When I try to reproduce the code with a current version of protostuff (1.3.8), I fail, because the class RuntimeSchema does not seem to exist. I searched the net for a current tutorial but all I could find was:
https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff/wiki/Examples
which, honestly, I don't understand.

Can someone help me understand how protostuff is supposed to be used in the current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked up on my own code to have a look for you, and here is what I am doing:

```
LinkedBuffer buffer = LinkedBuffer.allocate(2048);
Schema<Order> orderSchema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(Order.class);

ProtostuffIOUtil.toByteArray(order2, orderSchema, buffer);
buffer.clear();
```

So the same really as the examples. The only thing I can suggest doing is that your POM includes all three dependencies:

- Protostuff Runtime (the one you are probably missing)
- Protostuff API
- Protostuff Core

In the future the best thing to look at for a problem like this is always that you have all necessary dependencies.

Comment: Indeed, that was my problem. Thank you!